# How to use es6 import for importing electron instead of require function

Tags: typescript, electron, importerror

I am new to electron and making GUIs using node Js. I referred the docs of electron and there they used require statement to import the module. When I tried to import it using an ES6 import I faced an error.

[image]

> npm version - 6.14.15

> node version - v14.17.6

> electron version - 16.0.7

package.json file looks something like this -

```json
{
  "name": "typing-speed-tester",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a typing speed tester which will calculate your typing speed and accuracy of the typed words",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "Gahan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^16.0.7"
  }
}
```

This is the index.ts file

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const createWindow = () => {
    const Window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800, height: 600
    })
    Window.loadFile("index.html")
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
})
```

Here I want to replace the require with the `import` keyword
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try `import app from 'electron';`.

Comment: You can make things better by sharing `tsconfig.json`, `package.json` and contents of the file where the import is happening.

Comment: @NalinRanjan I have added the content of the package.json

Comment: What I have written is a different `import form`, other than `module import form`. No way I'm asking you not to include `BrowserWindow`.

Comment: can you also share your `tsconfig.json` and some content of file where this import is happening...

Comment: I have added the content of the file and I don't have any `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Can you please try, in your setup, `import Electron from 'electron'`, and then `const app = Electron.app; type BrowserWindow = Electron.BrowserWindow;`.

Comment: But you have given a `ts` file. Is it not a typescript solution?

Comment: I faced the same error again

Comment: Check if [this](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript/blob/master/src/main.ts) helps you. Otherwise let us know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241414/discussion-between-gahan-vig-and-nalin-ranjan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing a module resolution setting used by Ts compiler.

You can add a `tsconfig.json` file in your project root containing a `compilerOptions.module` value:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015"
    }
}
```

See [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) for further details.

Comment: Firstly it didn't worked but when I rerun my program it worked successfully. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GahanVig You're welcome. Happy to have helped you. Note that it maybe failed because you didn't compile your app before executing it. Here's an article about starting an electron project with Typescript:  https://dev.to/batajus/electron-quick-start-with-typescript-48h8